# Is it possible to access an instance of a variable in an array element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that JS isn't OOP but I would like to know whether it is possible to access an "instance" of a variable in an array element. I'll use an example to better illustrate this:

I have an array `gSzQuestions[]` with 10 similar string templates (which are tables) that contain some variables (let's say `q1, q2, q3, q4`). I would like to access them if this is possible, because let's take for example that `q` stands for question and there is a separate table to show the options for answering. If the user selects the wrong answer I would like to display (at the end of the program) which question is wrong.

If there isn't a way to access these variables, how can I store the history of the questions and answers to retrieve them later?

EDIT:
Let's say I have a `var questionString = '<table><td><tr>' + q1 + '</tr></td></table>` (shortened for succinctness purposes, the actual code is much longer). In the array `gSzQuestions` every time `functionA()` is called 10 instances of `questionString` will be stored, each of which contains a `q1`, where the value of it each instance is randomized with `Math.random()`. My question is, is there a way to access `q1` in `gSzQuestions[1]` and again in, for example, `gSzQuestions[8]`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you try simplifying and isolating the code that is relevant and post jsfiddle demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to access values stored inside arrays. One might say that is the primary purposes of arrays. You access array elements with `[]`

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry for that, I have done as you asked. I've made a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9PeBV/). I want to be able to display the questions that you've answered wrongly at the end page. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @meagar That wasn't what I was asking --- I wanted to know if it was possible to access a variable **inside** an array element.

Comment: if it's still a variable, you can.  When you concatenate it into a string, no.  e.g., `var g = 89; gSzQuestions[1] = g + 'text'; //can no longer access g.  the value would be '89text'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the variable concatenated with the string is evaluated before it is stored so everything is "flattened".

You can however make a sort of template for it and store the string and the variable as an object instead in the array:

```
var questions = [];

var question1 = {
    text: '<table><td><tr>{VAR}</tr></td></table>',
    variable: 1
}

var question2 = {
    text: '<table><td><tr>{VAR}</tr></td></table>',
    variable: 20
}

questions.push(question1);
questions.push(question2);
... etc...
```

Now you can extract the object containing the string and format the current variable:

```
var qIndex = 0;
var str = questions[qIndex].text.replace('{VAR}', questions[qIndex].variable);
```

### [Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/BVx2g/)

Instead of an object literal you can use this approach:

```
var Question = function(text, variable) {
    this.toString = function() {
        return text.replace('{VAR}', variable);
    }
}
```

Now store this as:

```
var questions = [
    new Question('This is value: {VAR}', 1),
    new Question('This is value: {VAR}', 20),
    new Question('This is value: {VAR}', 60),
]
```

Then get the formatted string:

```
alert(questions[0].toString());
```

### [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/uY59s/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second method was much easier to understand (albeit still difficult for a beginner like me) and does the job as well. Could you enlighten me as to what was going on in `var Question`?

Comment: @Xozzo it is simply assigning a function object to the variable. Using `new Question` creates a *new* instance of that object each time and uses the constructor (text, variable) as parameters where the arguments are stored. The toString() is our custom method inside the object which formats the two arguments the way we want.

Comment: That makes more sense now. I wasn't sure how you were overriding the `toString()` function to fit the issue. Thank you!